# Docker swarm services don't replicate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-registry, docker-image

I develop a docker swarm of 6 nodes and I trying to add services to them. I developed my swarm and I tried to add services with docker-complose.yml file. The file looks like this.

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    image: hotel_app_frontend_single_node_memdb
    entrypoint: frontend
    container_name: 'hotel_app_frontend'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always

  profile:
    build: .
    image: hotel_app_profile_single_node_memdb
    entrypoint: profile
    container_name: 'hotel_app_profile'
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    restart: always

  search:
    build: .
    image: hotel_app_search_single_node_memdb
    entrypoint: search
    container_name: 'hotel_app_search'
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    restart: always

  geo:
    build: .
    image: hotel_app_geo_single_node_memdb
    container_name: 'hotel_app_geo'
    entrypoint: geo
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    restart: always

  rate:
    build: .
    image: hotel_app_rate_single_node_memdb
    container_name: 'hotel_app_rate'
    entrypoint: rate
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"
    restart: always

  jaeger:
      image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
      container_name: 'hotel_app_jaeger'
      ports:
        - "14269"
        - "5778:5778"
        - "14268:14268"
        - "14267"
        - "16686:16686"
        - "5775:5775/udp"
        - "6831:6831/udp"
        - "6832:6832/udp"
      restart: always
```

I used this command. docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml mydep
When I am trying to see services this appears. Only the jaeger which I pull form web is replicated.

```
ID             NAME             MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                                         PORTS
xm3csgvlli9h   mydep_frontend   replicated   0/1        hotel_app_frontend_single_node_memdb:latest   *:8080->8080/tcp
ypaviqz5rrm6   mydep_geo        replicated   0/1        hotel_app_geo_single_node_memdb:latest        *:8083->8083/tcp
owp2x9p1xltl   mydep_jaeger     replicated   1/1        jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest               *:5778->5778/tcp, *:14268->14268/tcp, *:16686->16686/tcp, *:30000->14269/tcp, *:30001->14267/tcp, *:5775->5775/udp, *:6831-6832->6831-6832/udp
381u6hr6eh5b   mydep_profile    replicated   0/1        hotel_app_profile_single_node_memdb:latest    *:8081->8081/tcp
mbeb8w2r1hq4   mydep_rate       replicated   0/1        hotel_app_rate_single_node_memdb:latest       *:8084->8084/tcp
hrwyj1v55ao1   mydep_search     replicated   0/1        hotel_app_search_single_node_memdb:latest     *:8082->8082/tcp
```

I also try this command journalctl -f -n10

```
Nov 14 07:35:28 node0.vasilis-139127.ucy-cs499-dc-pg0.wisc.cloudlab.us systemd[6167]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Nov 14 07:35:28 node0.vasilis-139127.ucy-cs499-dc-pg0.wisc.cloudlab.us systemd[6167]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Nov 14 07:35:28 node0.vasilis-139127.ucy-cs499-dc-pg0.wisc.cloudlab.us systemd[6167]: Reached target Sockets.
Nov 14 07:35:28 node0.vasilis-139127.ucy-cs499-dc-pg0.wisc.cloudlab.us systemd[6167]: Reached target Paths.
Nov 14 07:35:28 node0.vasilis-139127.ucy-cs499-dc-pg0.wisc.cloudlab.us systemd[6167]: Reached target Timers.
Nov 14 07:35:28 node0.vasilis-139127.ucy-cs499-dc-pg0.wisc.cloudlab.us systemd[6167]: Reached target Basic System.
Nov 14 07:35:28 node0.vasilis-139127.ucy-cs499-dc-pg0.wisc.cloudlab.us systemd[6167]: Reached target Default.
Nov 14 07:35:28 node0.vasilis-139127.ucy-cs499-dc-pg0.wisc.cloudlab.us systemd[6167]: Startup finished in 61ms.
Nov 14 07:39:34 node0.vasilis-139127.ucy-cs499-dc-pg0.wisc.cloudlab.us sshd[6327]: Received disconnect from 194.42.11.22 port 62111:11: disconnected by user
Nov 14 07:39:34 node0.vasilis-139127.ucy-cs499-dc-pg0.wisc.cloudlab.us sshd[6327]: Disconnected from user vasilis 194.42.11.22 port 62111
```

Comment: What happens when you scale the services manually ?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing compose v2 syntax in a v3 file. The "restart", "container_name", and "build" steps do not apply in swarm. And the image names need specify the names that exist in a registry which you would be able to access with `docker pull`.

Comment: The image is local. I must push it to a registry?

Comment: To deploy in swarm, you must push to a registry.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem. The image was private in the docker hub account. For this reason, it was necessary to docker login on other worker nodes.